# Pattern matching during pipe

Tags: elixir

I've to parse an xml document, extracting an integer from an xml node.

Currently I have:

```
try do
  Floki.find(node, "stat[type='jersey_num']")
    |> Floki.text
    |> Integer.parse
    |> elem(0)
rescue
  e -> nil
end
```

which works fine but I don't like having to rescue everything, I would like to do something like:

```
Floki.find(node, "stat[type='jersey_num']")
  |> Floki.text
  |> case Integer.parse do
    { int, _binary } -> int
    _                -> nil
  end
```

but I get `unhandled operator ->` in the fourth line, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to pipe into `Integer.parse` first and then into `case`:

```
defmodule MyInteger do
  def parse(string) do
    string
    |> Integer.parse
    |> case do
         {int, _} -> int
         _ -> nil
       end
  end
end
```

Demo:

```
iex(1)> MyInteger.parse "123"
123
iex(2)> MyInteger.parse "abc"
nil
```

Note that `MyInteger.parse "123abc" #=> 123`, so you might want to change your pattern match to be `{int, ""} -> int`, if you want the same behavior as `Integer.parse/1`.

Comment: Just make sure to put the case expression into its own function. Pipe expressions shouldn't be longer than one line for readability.

Comment: @tkowal even if it's the last line? sometimes like in this case you match to either return something (and maybe pipe again) or exit completely

Comment: `case do {int, _} -> int; _ -> nil end` for the one-line win! From: [Elixir case on a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229946/elixir-case-on-a-single-line).

Comment: Nice, that's exactly what I was trying to do.  Though I would say marginally more readable to write `case Integer.parse(string) do`.  Pipelines are great but you can overuse them!