# Elixir case on a single line

Tags: elixir

I would like to have the following case on a single line:

```
case s do
  :a -> :b
  :b -> :a
end
```

The macro `case` is defined as `case(condition, clauses)`. The following

```
quote do
  case s do
    :a -> :b
    :b -> :a
  end
end
```

gives:

```
{:case, [],
 [{:s, [], Elixir}, [do: [{:->, [], [[:a], :b]}, {:->, [], [[:b], :a]}]]]}
```

and from here should be possible to go back to `case(s, ???)`

Comment: You mean `Macro.to_string({:case, [],
 [{:s, [], Elixir}, [do: [{:->, [], [[:a], :b]}, {:->, [], [[:b], :a]}]]]})`? If not, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: No, I would like to put the 4 lines of the first block on a single line (with the correct syntax). The rest of my question is how I started to reason on it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two possible ways to do this. One from the answer above is to inline the `do end` calls obtaining:

```
case s do :a -> :b; :b -> :a end
```

Another one is to use `, do:` keyword version of a block. We need to group the two expressions - otherwise the compiler wouldn't know both clauses are part of the case:

```
case s, do: (:a -> :b; :b -> :a)
```

Without the parens the expression would be parsed as:

```
(case s, do: :a -> :b); :b -> :a
```

And `:b -> :a` on it's own is not a valid expression in elixir.

Comment: Until I read the below answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230034/118153) I'd completely missed the `;` and read it as `,`.

Comment: Note that `mix format` will convert the one liner into multiline case statement

Answer (score 8):

Apparently, you can use `;` to achieve what you want:

```
 case s do :a -> :b; :b -> :a end
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried all combinations, but I never thought about this one, because in elixir I had always `, do:`